# ms access form add record with condition

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm in self training and I want to create a form with conditions but I don't find anything .

I have two tables, and I want to create a form that add a row in eatch table.

[image]

I made this form.
[image]

I want to exclude spouse field when the no radio button is checked.

I tried several things but nothing works.

If you have tracks or lessons that could help me.

Comment: Spouse should not be in a separate table. Have all people in one table and just save record ID of spouse into person_spouse field. Research recursive database. This is a situation where table is joined to itself in query to associated related records.

Comment: I have made a relation between person_id and person_spouse but I can't figure out how to make the form..

Comment: Just bind form to table and have a combobox to select spouse. If there is no record in table for person who is spouse, use combobox NotInList event to add record.